# Change ' and ˜ to not produce accent

Tags: keyboard, development

I am using a MacBook Pro Retina with US international keyboard layout, latest OS. Is there a way to change ˜ to produce ~ without pressing the space after it? And is there a way to configure ' to work the same way? Like I don't need accents so If I type 'a I want to get 'a and not á without the extra space key press.